# Axios does not return data when requesting quickly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, lumen

I use vue as front end, and lumen as back end, this is my code

```
export default {
   name: 'App',
   data() {
      myData: []
   },
   methods: {
      getData() {
         let self = this;
         this.axios.get('my_url_api').then( res => {
           self.myData = res.data;
           console.log(res.data.length); // I try to count my data after delete, nothing update
         }).catch( err => {
           console.log(err.response);
         });
      },

      _delete(){
         let self = this;
         this.axios.delete('my_url_api/'+dataId).then(() => {
            self.getData(); // myData not updated after delete
         }).catch( err => {
            console.log(err.response);
         });
      }

   }
}
```

`myData: []` not updated after I create (axios.post), update (axios.put), and delete (axios.delete) quickly, when I check my database the datas has been deleted), but it's work fine when I create update or delete data then I wait for few seconds to create, update or delete again. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Change `self.getData()` to `this.getData()` inside `_delete()` method.

```
_delete(){
     this.axios.delete('my_url_api/'+dataId).then(() => {
        // use this, cause inside arrow function 'this' does not update
        setTimeout(() => {
           this.getData();
        }, 200); // wait 200 ms, then invoke getData()
     }).catch( err => {
        ...
     });
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but still not work, sometimes data is loaded sometimes not

Comment: It seems not to be. Anyway, where you initialize `dataId` when calling delete api?

Comment: `dataId` is from `data(){ return }` I forgot to put `this.dataId`, but still not update when `_delete()` is called, I try to display number of data on `getDetail()` method with `res.data.length`, sometimes data is changed sometimes not, when I check in database data has been deleted. help :(

Comment: ok. Since "sometimes data is loaded sometimes not ", I guess it's needed some time to update in Backened. You can wait 200 milliseconds then invoke `getData()`.